# exist another pattern to replace DTO pattern in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am assigned a project in java where the patron DTO is used, but I consulted it that is (dto) disused [how evil are data transfer objects](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_evil_are_actually_data)  or is [Is DTO pattern deprecated or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237946/is-dto-pattern-deprecated-or-not)

**exist another pattern that you will recommend?**

I come from Entity Frame-w and c# world where exist repository and unit of work pattern

Note: I have to use JAx RS web service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to point a concept (not sure it'll solve your case) - [RemoteFacade](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/remoteFacade.html)
is a good optional fit for the Persistence layer. Remote Facade In an object-oriented model, you do best with small objects that have small methods. This gives you lots of opportunity for control and substitution of behavior, and to use good intention revealing naming to make an application easier to understand. One of the consequences of such fine-grained behavior is that there's usually a great deal of interaction between objects, and that interac-tion usually requires lots of method invocations.