# What is java pojo class, java bean, normal class?

Tags: java, class, javabeans, pojo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between DTO, VO, POJO, JavaBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans)

Hi please don't say my question is duplicate :-) I saw all questions but didn't understand the exact difference.

Can someone explain what is `POJO`, `Bean`, `Normal Class` in easy language?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

1. `Normal Class`: A Java class
2. `Java Beans`:

   - All properties private (use getters/setters)
   - A public no-argument constructor
   - Implements Serializable.
3. `Pojo`:
   Plain Old Java Object is a Java object not bound by any restriction other than those forced by the Java Language Specification. I.e., a POJO should not have to

   - Extend prespecified classes
   - Implement prespecified interface
   - Contain prespecified annotations

Comment: I heard except no-argument constructor both pojo and bean are same right ?

Comment: java bean, implement Serializable means every time we must implement Serializable manually ?

Comment: A public no-argument constructor:
I think every class has its own no-argument constructor if am correct, why you specified only for bean only ? sorry if am wrong am fresher.

Comment: if you did not specify any constructor for a class then only java will create no-argument constructor implicitly.

Comment: So all normal Java classes are POJOs?

Comment: @firstpostcommenter It might be useful to get a description of what POJO is from the [person who coined the term](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/POJO.html).  ("encoding business logic into regular java objects rather than using Entity Beans"). In other words, POJO was a name to given to describe "plain old java objects" *in order to* contrast Java beans. POJOs are domain/business objects specific,  so not necessarily all Java classes are POJOs

Answer (score 29):

POJO stands for Plain Old Java Object, and would be used to describe the same things as a "Normal Class" whereas a JavaBean follows a set of rules. Most commonly Beans use getters and setters to protect their member variables, which are typically set to private and have a no-argument public constructor. Wikipedia has a pretty good rundown of JavaBeans: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans

POJO is usually used to describe a class that doesn't need to be a subclass of anything, or implement specific interfaces, or follow a specific pattern.

Comment: also, JavaBeans should implement the Serializable interface.

Comment: I didn't during creating a bean in spring.

Answer (score 8):

POJO = Plain Old Java Object. It has properties, getters and setters for respective properties. It may also override `Object.toString()` and `Object.equals()`.

Java Beans : See [Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans).

Normal Class : Any java Class.

Comment: the only difference between a POJO and Beans is that Beans should implement Serializable interface?