# Is there any Difference between Standalone class and pojo class?

Tags: java

Is there any Difference between Standalone class and pojo class? Or these two are actually same?

Comment: What's a "standalone" class?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517905/what-is-java-pojo-class-java-bean-normal-class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between DTO, VO, POJO, JavaBeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is probably "No".

POJO means "plain old Java object" meaning "object that doesn't do anything special to integrate with our system".
So if the class doesn't extend/implement anything and contains mostly values with getters and setters you can treat it as POJO.

"Standalone" is not a common term for any class kind. But I've googled some uses of "standalone class" phrase and they mean a class that contain `main()` method. So this is definitely not the same as POJO.

Answer (score -1):

POJO (Plain Old Java Object) that is used frequently in a modern Java without additional code generated using it such as stubs or proxies.

Comment: It is saying both are same: "http://www.coolinterview.com/interview/16387/"