# How To Search In Listview From Toolbar In Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I was using this code to search from my MainActivity Toolbar in a ListView:

```
    SearchView searchView;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;

}
```

But now I moved my Listview to a fragment, how can I pass the adapter from the fragment to the main activity? How can I update the typing?
Is there any better way then passing the adapter?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach can be using [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/). It's really helpful in a scenario like this in which we have to pass certain data from an Activity to a Fragment.

For using EventBus, you need to define a [POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517905/what-is-java-pojo-class-java-bean-normal-class) class, somewhat like this:

```
class SearchQueryEvent {
    String query;

    public SearchQueryEvent(String query) {
        this.query=query;
    }

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }
}
```

Now, your code should be modified like this:

**MainActivity.java**

```
SearchView searchView;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new SearchQueryEvent(s));
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;

}
```

**YourFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onSearchQuery(SearchQueryEvent event) {
    String query=event.getQuery();
    adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'EventBus', do I have to import something?

Comment: Yes, add the following line inside your build.gradle (app) where all the 'compile' statements are written. `compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'`

Comment: I did it but it doesn't apply the filter to the adapter, and in the fragment.java `.unsubscribe(this);` and `.subscribe(this);` give me the error "Cannot resolve method", how can I do?

Comment: The void onSearchQuery in the fragment is never used

Comment: After adding the 'compile' statement, you've to build the entire project to get the references. Once the project is rebuilt, you'll be able to see the methods in EventBus class.

Comment: I did it all, but look here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AniEkQ5k9-XDnHli-hT2uu6eTcxL    this is what happens and I'm not able to search from the fragment. I don't know what I do wrong

Comment: I am really sorry. Please see the updated code. You'll get that running now. Sorry again for silly mistake.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry at all, that's perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try This code,

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#009688" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="ru.lemmaproj.toolbar_search.MainActivityFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**search_layout.xml :**

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

**MainActivityFragment.java :**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String[] items = new String[] { "Android", "iOS", "Windows Phone",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2" };

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I can't make it work in my application. I copied the last part of the fragment.java (from onActivityCreated), and changed just the layout references, but it crashes when I try to run

Answer (score 1):

1-> Create a static method in fragment

```
public static void doSearch(String query){
    yourAdapter.filter(query);
}
```

2-> Call this method from activity on *onQueryTextChange* method and pass the query you want to search

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

    MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchViewShop = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchViewShop.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            YourFragment.doSearch(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```