# How to pass arguments to a Fragment which is currently active?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity, which instantiates 4 different fragments based on button clicks. 
I have to pass additional values to my fragment which is currently active.

Initially, when I pass values via setArguments, the values are being passed. But 2nd time the values are not passed to Fragment.

I tried to Log and put breakpoints in onCreate and onCreateView methods, but these methods are not being called at all 2nd time.

Here is my code

**Code in Activity**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("from", "1");
bundle.putString("label","One");

MyFragment1 myFragment1 = new MyFragment1();
myFragment1.setArguments(bundle);
getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.addToBackStack(null)
.replace(R.id.fragment1, myFragment1)
.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

**Code in Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Bundle b = getArguments();
    if(b!=null)
    { 

    }


}
```

Comment: `public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {` intead of this try to get inside `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

Comment: You can find a solution to the similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454596/how-to-search-in-listview-from-toolbar-in-fragment/41463851#41463851

Answer (score 0):

From Activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("from", "1");
bundle.putString("label","One");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String label = getArguments().getString("label");    
    int i=getArguments().getInt("from"); 
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

I gave this line of code in onCreate in Activity.

```
MyFragment1 myFragment1 = new MyFragment1();
```

I had to reinstatitate before passing it to the fragment.