# how to store and compare unique pairs in java? which data structure is useful?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a list of Notification's objects, its name is notifications.I map it in a HashMap:

```
Map<String, String> recipientByMedia = new HashMap<>();
        for (Notification obj : notifications) {
            recipientByMedia.put(obj.getMedia(), obj.getRecipient());
        }
```

my notification list have tow different value for "IM" :

```
"IM" : "+928292929"
"IM" : "test@yahoo.com"
```

I know, HashMap overrides new "IM" instead oldest one. finally, I want to use this HashMap to using in "Mockoto.assertEqual" .like this:

```
assertEquals(recipientByMedia.get("IM"), contact.getSmsNumber());
assertEquals(recipientByMedia.get("IM"), contact.getImAddress());
```

one of these test will fail. how can I compare "IM" in my test? which data structure can I use instead of HashMap?

Answer (score 1):

i think, it is a feature of hash map which makes a one to one relation between domain and range.

I suggest you to make different keys. like

```
assertEquals(recipientByMedia.get("IM0"), contact.getSmsNumber());
assertEquals(recipientByMedia.get("IM1"), contact.getImAddress());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the class `Notification` seems to be the single source of truth, why do you need a different data structure? What are you trying to accomplish with the `Map`?

If you want to look up the properties of the `Notification` object in your list where `getMedia` is let's say `"IM"` you could just filter the list and access the properties directly from the object that was meant to hold this kind of information:

```
String recipient = notifications.stream()
  .filter(n -> "IM".equals(n.getMedia()))
  .findFirst()
  .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(/* not in the list */))
  .getRecipient();
```

If this is not the case and you want to compose data from multiple sources, create [POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517905/what-is-java-pojo-class-java-bean-normal-class)s for the exact purpose of holding the necessary information, or simply use the 2 data sources to get the combined information if it's more readable for some purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model with setter and getter and then use ArrayList instead of Hashmap like this `private ArrayList<StudentsDetail> arraylist;` and then inside of your for loop add this `arraylist.add(new StudensDetail(obj.getMedia(),  obj.getRecipient()));` and when you wanted to get values write this code inside your for loop `id = arraylist.get(i).getId();`

and this is the model

```
public class StudentDetails {
private String name;
private String id;

public StudentDetails(String name, String id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Comment: thank you. it is great. but, How can I compare these valued???? "IM" has tow values and I want to test both values. How can I do it????