# insert different value to object as json

Tags: java

i want my json like this

```
{"struct":{"member":[{"name":"Testname","value":{"string":"TestString"}},{"name":"Testname2","value":{"string":"TestString2"}}]}}
```

but when i run the code the result is like this

```
{"struct":{"member":[{"name":"Testname","value":{"string":"TestString2"}},{"name":"Testname2","value":{"string":"TestString2"}}]}}
```

this is my code

```
Stringcont.setstring("TestString");
Stringcont.setstring("TestString2");
Membercont.add(new Membercont("Testname",Stringcont));
Membercont.add(new Membercont("Testname2",Stringcont));

Structcont.setmember(Membercont);
Objectcont.setstruct(Structcont);
Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(Objectcont));
```

Comment: this is because you add the same object with different keys, try instantiating  another  object rather.

Comment: I see, it works thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the same `Stringcont` object twice. First time to `"TestString"`, then to `"TestString2"`. Try using the `add` method before setting it to `"TestString2"` or use different objects.

```
Stringcont.setstring("TestString");
Membercont.add(new Membercont("Testname",Stringcont));
Stringcont.setstring("TestString2");
Membercont.add(new Membercont("Testname2",Stringcont));
```

Comment: are you using any pojo class if yes please share i will tell how you can do that

Comment: thank you, but i want to insert different value in same object.

Comment: what does pojo class means? sorry i'm newbie in java @harkeshkumar

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "different value in same object"?

Comment: class that have getter and setter

Comment: @AndikaRistianNugraha Refer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517905/what-is-java-pojo-class-java-bean-normal-class

Comment: @AlvaroLemos, if you look at the code the value of object "Stringcont" is changing to "TestingString2" before adding "TestingString" to "Membercont" object. So, if you look at the solution provided, we are first adding  "TestingString" then adding "TestingString2".

Comment: @PallavKabra I see now, makes sense