# Request String [] + String as Json from rest controller method

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I've been searching around here for a solution , but I found nothing useful for my case.

My Dao needs a `String[]` and a single `String`, so I did this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" })
public void newRent(@RequestBody String[] isbn,String username) {
    rentService.newRent(isbn, username);
}
```

Now, I'm trying to do a `POST` from *Postman* calling the mapped link, but I keep getting method not allowed (`405`).

I tried a lot, this looks the best ways to do it, but still doesn't work.

```
[
 { {   "isbn":"123"},{"isbn":"1234"},
 { "username" : "zappa"}
]
```

or

```
{
  "isbn": ["123", "1234"],
  "username": "zappa"
}
```

Am I missing something? cant figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this is the correct JSON (the other one is incorrect, [check it here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)):

```
{
  "isbn": ["123", "1234"],
  "username": "zappa"
}
```

Now, in order to get those values you need to use [`@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) along with some [POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517905/what-is-java-pojo-class-java-bean-normal-class), [JavaBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans) or [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), in order to get the values correctly. For example with a Map it would be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" })
public void newRent(@RequestBody Map data) {
    rentService.newRent((String [])data.get("isbn"), data.get("username").toString());
}
```

With a POJO, it would be something like this:

```
public class RentEntity {
    private String[] isbn;
    private String username;

    public String[] getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String[] isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" })
public void newRent(@RequestBody RentEntity data) {
    rentService.newRent(data.getIsbn(), data.getUsername());
}
```

**Additional info**

- You can generate POJOs automatically from JSONs using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new entity `Rent`

```
public class Rent{public string[] isbn; public string username;}
```

Then you change your method to:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" })
public void newRent(@RequestBody Rent rentRequest) {
    rentService.newRent(rentRequest.isbn, rentRequest.username);
}
```