# Sort a List of Objects based on runtime property

Tags: java, list, sorting, reflection, comparator

I have a `List` of [Value Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans) [VO]. These Objects have many properties and corresponding get/set methods. I want to sort this `List` based on a property which I'll be getting in runtime.
Let me explain in detail...

My VO is like this:

```
public class Employee {
    String name;
    String id;

    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I will be getting a string `sortType` in runtime, which can be either `"id"` or `"name"`. I want to sort the list based on the value of the `String`.

I have tried to use `Comparator` and reflection together, but no luck. May be I didn't use it properly. I don’t want to use conditional `if` block branching to create whichever new specific `Comparator` [anonymous inner Class] is needed (at the runtime). Any other thoughts?

---

The try catch should be inside the new class. Here is the working code. If you want to use a separate class for `Comparator`, please find it in @Bohemian's comment below.

```
        String sortType = "name"; // determined at runtime
        Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<Employee>() {
        public int compare(Employee c1, Employee c2) {
            try{
            Method m = c1.getClass().getMethod("get" + StringUtils.capitalize(sortType));
            String s1 = (String)m.invoke(c1);
            String s2 = (String)m.invoke(c2);
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
       });
```

Comment: Please use the appropriate language tag.

Comment: If you post your code which used reflection, we might be able to tell you what went wrong…

Comment: I've added the code I tried with.

Comment: Is the try block not applicable to the inner class which will be created by new Comparator() ? I'm just wondering. I'm getting the errors on the first 3 lines of compare() method.

Comment: Guys.. Should I be deleting all the piece of codes which didn't work from the post? This is my first post and don't have much idea about the proceedings.

Comment: In this case, I think it would be fine to delete old code and only show the current version.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the variable sort is the one which will be passed in the runtime, I've followed bohemian's way to avoid confusion and updated the code.

Comment: @jahroy: Well, there is. Its in the same link you posted. public Method getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)

Comment: Why don't you want to use an `if` statement?  It exactly fits the requirements here.  Do you _ever_ use `if` statement branches at all, or do you just not like them in general?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a `Comparator` for the job:

```
public class EmployeeComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

    private final String type;

    public EmployeeComparator (String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        if (type.equals("name")) {
             return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
        }
        return e1.getId().compareTo(e2.getId());
    }

}
```

Then to use it

```
String type = "name"; // determined at runtime
Collections.sort(list, new EmployeeComparator(type));
```

The reflective version would be similar, except you would look for a method on the object of "get" + type (capitalised) and invoke that and hard cast it to Comparable and use compareTo (I'll try to show the code, but I'm using my iPhone and its a bit of a stretch, but here goes)

```
public class DynamicComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
    private final String type;
    // pass in type capitalised, eg "Name" 
    // ie the getter method name minus the "get"
    public DynamicComparator (String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        // try-catch omitted 
        Method m = o1.getClass().getMethod("get" + type);
        String s1 = (String)m.invoke(o1);
        String s2 = (String)m.invoke(o2);
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}
```

---

OK... Here's how to do it *without* creating a class, using an anonymous class (with exception handling so code compiles):

```
List<?> list;
final String attribute = "Name"; // for example. Also, this is case-sensitive
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Object>() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        try {
            Method m = o1.getClass().getMethod("get" + attribute);
            // Assume String type. If different, you must handle each type
            String s1 = (String) m.invoke(o1);
            String s2 = (String) m.invoke(o2);
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        // simply re-throw checked exceptions wrapped in an unchecked exception
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); 
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks good and simple. Thanks !! Will try and let you know.

Comment: Awesome man..!! This is exactly what I've been looking for ! Let me try it.

Comment: This exception handling is killing me again. I tried to do it in a single shot instead of creating a class and I'm getting all sorts of exceptions now. Here's what I tried.

Comment: You should create a Comparator class.  That's what allows you to _construct_ a Comparator at runtime with the specified sort field (by passing it in a constructor). Your most recently posted code does not allow for any way to specify the sort field.  @Bohemian's code allows the client code to specify the sort field by passing a String parameter in the Comparator's constructor.

Comment: The code which I posted have a 'sort' variable inside the getMethod which can be passed in runtime. I thought its a waste to create a new class, but I haven't tested this yet. Will let you know if it works.

Comment: What makes you think it's a "_waste_" to create a class?

Comment: Well, if we can get the desired result without creating a new class, and without any hit on performance, its better to follow the shortest  way to achieve it right.

Comment: @jijo You could do all this using an anonymous class. See edited answer for the requried kung fu

Comment: Thank You !! Is there any performance impact or any other side effect in using this way instead of creating a new class?

Comment: @jijo no impact at all. The compiler creates a class for you, so performance is identical. The only impact is that your colleagues will be in awe of your java king fu :)

Comment: @jio if you care about performance, you should not use reflection. It is sloooooooooooooooow. If you care about runtime performance then create an `if/else` block with ten branches, one for each attribute! (Also, that safe against injection attacks…)

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

- get the name of the field from the client
- build the name of the getter -> "get" + field name (after capitalizing the first character)
- try to find the method with reflection by using [Class.getDeclaredMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)
- if found, invoke the returned Method object on two instances of your *VO* class
- use the results of the invoked getter methods for sorting

Comment: You might just as well access the fields (if the getters are really that trivial).

Comment: Yeah just a call to `employee.getClass().getField(fieldName)` would be more maintainable/readable: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1):

[Keep it simple!](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?KeepItSimple)

If the choice is only `id` or `name`—use an if statement.

Picking between two choices. That’s what if has been invented for.

Or, if it is many properties, then use reflection, or store the data in a `Map` in the first place. Sometimes `Map` is better than an class. In particular if your VO has not methods other than getters and setters.

Caution though, using reflection is might be unsafe in this case as your client might inject any term in the CGI parameters in an attack akin to SQL injection.

Comment: The OP states that his class has _many_ properties.  I think he just showed two of them to keep it simple.

Comment: Thats the problem. Its not just id and name, my VO is quite large with around 10+ properties in it.

Comment: Added rational on why *NOT* using reflection.

Comment: The OP will surely have an opportunity to constrain the input... Don't see any risk of injection attack here.

Comment: Okay, if it is all properties, then use reflection—or store the data in a `Map` in the first place. Sometimes `Map` is better than an object. In particular if your VO has not methods other than getters and setters.

Comment: _Many_ attributes can also describe including _just 2 attributes_.  If the Question intended to ask about many more than 2 attributes, it should have mentioned that - particularly when it explicitly is coded with just the 2 attributes, without mentioning that's just an example (and instead many more fields are secretly desired to be accounted for...).

Comment: Better yet - actually _code into the question_ the secret 10+ properties.  Why not do that?  The Question is literally asking something different otherwise.

Comment: With the Question _as it has been posed_, I agree that just an `if` statement would actually be the best solution: The complexity added of otherwise using Reflection is not worth just trying to avoid `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

*For whatever reason you don't want to use an `if` statement*... **Leverage using [`java.lang.reflect.Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField-java.lang.String-)**:

```
String sortType = "name"; // determined at runtime
Comparator<Employee> comparator = new Comparator<Employee>(){
    public int compare(Employee e0, Employee e1){
        try {
            Field sortField = e0.getClass().getField(sortType);
            return sortField.get(e0).toString()
                       .compareTo(sortField.get(e1).toString()));

        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Couldn't get field with name " + sortType, e);
        }
    };
}
```

*But that only works for String fields* - **below handles any type of Field (or at least, `Comparable` fields)**:

```
String sortType = "name"; // determined at runtime
Comparator<Employee> comparator = new Comparator<Employee>(){
    public int compare(Employee e0, Employee e1){
        try {
            Field sortField = e0.getClass().getField(sortType);
            Comparable<Object> comparable0
                = (Comparable<Object>) sortField.get(e0);
            Comparable<Object> comparable1
                = (Comparable<Object>) sortField.get(e1);

            return comparable0.compareTo(comparable1);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                          "Couldn't get field with name " + sortType, e);
        }
    };
}
```

** Note still however that *won't ignore case for `String`/`Character`/`char`* (although it *will account for negative numbers*) - for example, that would order capital `"Z"` before lowercase `"a"`.
If you want to account for *both* of those cases, I don't see a way around (wait for it...) an `if` statement!

You can see a full implementation of handling all those cases, plus the below cases as well, in my [`JavaSortAnyTopLevelValueObject`](https://github.com/cellepo/JavaSortAnyTopLevelValueObject) Github project (available in dependency JAR too):

- Handles *multiple* sort-tie *precedence* fields (i.e: sort first by precedence0, sort second by precedence1 [in case of ties], sort third by ...)
- Handles sorting *ascending/descending*, by each sort parameter
- Handles any top-level, `public` (or otherwise visible modifier from call-location) field type of {`primitive`, `Boxed Primitive`, or `String`}
- Ignores character casing