# What is a POJO which overrides equals() and hashCode() called?

Tags: java

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans) explains a lot about Java conventions (*I'm not sure how exactly they call this*).

I'm just curious, is there any name given for a simple class (or POJO) which overrides equals() and hashCode() methods?

Comment: I think it's still called a POJO. `equals` and `hashCode` are not considered "extra" or "fancy" methods -- they're a natural part of any plain ol' Java object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would name it: **AGoodCandidateForHashTableContentPOJO** => Java creators guys probably thought about that but no, there isn't a special naming for hashcode/equals concept ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no specific name for such POJO :)