# Programming difference between POJO and Bean

Tags: java, javabeans, pojo

I have the following two classes. Can I say the first one is a POJO class and the second one as a Bean class?

1) POJO class, since it has only getter and setter method, and all the member are declared as private

```
public class POJO {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId() {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName() {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

2) Bean class - all the member variables are private, has getters and setters and implements `Serializable` interface

```
public class Bean implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

It also has a no-arg constructor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only difference is bean can be serialized.

From Java docs - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized. All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable. The serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only to identify the semantics of being serializable.

Comment: that means if i implement java.io.Serializable interface , it is a bean otherwise a pojo class. @ninad Pingale

Comment: And the bean, need a constructor, without arguments :)

Answer (score 3):

the JavaBean class must implement either Serializable or Externalizable, must have a no-arg constructor,all JavaBean properties must public setter and getter methods (as appropriate)
all JavaBean instance variables should be private

Comment: can i have a example for no-arg constructor. Thanks in advance

Comment: public class TestBean implements java.io.Serializable {
 
    private String name;
  
    /** No-arg constructor (takes no arguments). */
    public TestBean() {
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
 
   
    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }}

Comment: If no arg constructor is absent in definition of POJO, But Serializable has been implemented in a POJO, would it be considered as a Bean ?

Comment: A Javabean SHOULD, not MUST implement Serializable