# Why PasswordField use String instead of char[] in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

String is *vulnerable* for password values. I noticed that Vaadin [`PasswordField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/PasswordField.html) manipulates *password* as a `String`.

Following is  default constructor of [`PasswordField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/PasswordField.html),

```
public PasswordField() {
  setValue("");
}
```

My questions :

- Is it safe to use [`PasswordField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/PasswordField.html) in Vaadin ?
- What internal API does to *assure* the safety of the password ?

Comment: I don't see how using a string is vulnerable. Strings are also used in other java frameworks. Besides, regex could be used to set a pattern for the password.

Comment: @cdaiga [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords-in-java) where they explain why  `char[]` is more secure than  `String`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** Vaadin [`PasswordField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/PasswordField.html) is a simple [`TextField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TextField.html). The input is hidden just in client-side, in server-side is transmitted in clear text.

Although you can use [`getConvertedValue()`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#getConvertedValue()) and [`setConvertedValue(Object value)`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#setConvertedValue(java.lang.Object)) for getting/setting the value in your own type. Note that you have to set the [`setConverter(Converter<T,?> converter)`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#setConverter(com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter)) before using it.

Here you have an example of how to use properly the conversation: [Creating your own converter for String - MyType conversion](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+your+own+converter+for+String+-+MyType+conversion)

---

**FULL EXPLANATION**

Vaadin [`TextField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TextField.html), [`PasswordField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/PasswordField.html) and [`TextArea`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TextArea.html) are all children of [`AbstractField<String>`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html).

[image: Vaadin Docs TextField]

In detail:

```
java.lang.Object
  |_ com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector
       |_ com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent
            |_ com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField<java.lang.String>
                 |_ com.vaadin.ui.AbstractTextField
```

[`PasswordField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/PasswordField.html) works with `String` because of its parents, otherwise it should have implemented `AbstractField<char[]>`.

In addition in the [`PasswordField` section from Vaadin Docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-passwordfield.html) says explicitly:

> You should note that the [`PasswordField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/PasswordField.html) hides the input **only from "over the shoulder" visual observation**. Unless the server connection is encrypted with a secure connection, such as HTTPS, the **input is transmitted in clear text** and may be intercepted by anyone with low-level access to the network. Also phishing attacks that intercept the input in the browser may be possible by exploiting JavaScript execution security holes in the browser.

---

**Although** [`AbstractField<T>`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html) has [`getConvertedValue()`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#getConvertedValue()) and [`setConvertedValue(Object value)`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#setConvertedValue(java.lang.Object)) which allow to get/set the value in the `Object` you prefer. Note that before using it you need to set [`setConverter(Converter<T,?> converter)`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#setConverter(com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter)).

Here you have an example of how to use properly the conversation: [Creating your own converter for String - MyType conversion](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+your+own+converter+for+String+-+MyType+conversion)

In short from the example:

`Name` is a simple [POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans) with `firstName` and `lastName` fields and their getter/setter.

Converter class

```
public class StringToNameConverter implements Converter<String, Name> {

    public Name convertToModel(String text, Locale locale) {
        String[] parts = text.split(" ");
        return new Name(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }

    public String convertToPresentation(Name name, Locale locale)
            throws ConversionException {
        return name.getFirstName() + " " + name.getLastName();
    }

    public Class<Name> getModelType() {
        return Name.class;
    }

    public Class<String> getPresentationType() {
        return String.class;
    }
}
```

Main class

```
Name name = new Name("Rudolph", "Reindeer");
final TextField textField = new TextField("Name");
textField.setConverter(new StringToNameConverter());
textField.setConvertedValue(name);
addComponent(textField);
addComponent(new Button("Submit value", new ClickListener() {

    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Name name = (Name) textField.getConvertedValue();
    }

}));
```

---

**Full source**

- [`com.vaadin.ui.PasswordField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/PasswordField.html)
- [`com.vaadin.ui.TextField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TextField.html)
- [`com.vaadin.ui.TextArea`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TextArea.html)
- [`com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField<T>`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html)
- [`com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField<T>#getConvertedValue()`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#getConvertedValue())
- [`com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField<T>#setConvertedValue(Object value)`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#setConvertedValue(java.lang.Object))
- [`com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField<T>#setConverter(Converter<T,?> converter)`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#setConverter(com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter))
- [Vaadin Docs `TextField`](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-textfield.html)
- [Vaadin Docs `PasswordField`](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-passwordfield.html)
- Example:[Creating your own converter for String - MyType conversion](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+your+own+converter+for+String+-+MyType+conversion)
- [Difference between DTO, VO, POJO, JavaBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans)
- [Morfic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38893074/1685157)

Answer (score 3):

A little late to this party, but I'd like to add my 2 cents to what's already been discussed.

It may be purely confort and code reuse, as [`PasswordField`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/PasswordField.java) just extends [`AbstractTextField`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractTextField.java) on the BE side which is basically an [`AbstractField<String>`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.java) so all the value manipulation logic, event handling, etc is already there.

Otherwise one would probably have to implement an `AbstractField<char[]>` and copy-paste pretty much everything from `AbstractTextField` just for this. Or to generify `AbstractTextField` or something similar...

Either way, as already stated, an attacker would require access to the server to dump the memory, case in which you may have bigger problems, be it from outside or inside the organisation (there surely are cases in which own employees have done harm for some reasons) :-)

Regarding the FE, the [`VPasswordField`](http://VPasswordField) counterpart creates [an input of type password](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#createInputPassword()), and the security concerns in respect to the the FE-BE communication have already been discussed in Paolo Forgia's answer.

Answer (score 2):

When vaadin codes runs in your web browser it is not in a JVM anymore, so using String is ok in this case. The password will be stored as Java String in the server side, so in order to access that password String, an attacker has to access your server.

You should be looking at how that password field is handled in the generated javascript.