# Abstract function with different parameters

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract

I want to declare an abstract class with an abstract function `calc()` and use this with different types of parameter.

```
public abstract class AbstractCalculation{
    public abstract double calc();
    ...
}

public StringClass extends AbstractCalculation{
    public double calc(String a, String b);
}

public DoubleClass extends AbstractCalculation{
    public double calc(double a, double b);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you mean to use Generics like this :

```
public abstract class AbstractCalculation<T> {
    public abstract double calc(T...params);//Here you can pass N param with any type
}
```

---

To extends from this abstract class, you can use :

```
public class DoubleClass extends AbstractCalculation<Double> {

    @Override
    public double calc(Double... params) {
        //Your action here
    }
}

public class StringClass extends AbstractCalculation<String> {

    @Override
    public double calc(String... params) {
        //Your action here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Generics https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

```
public abstract class Calculator<T, R>{
    public  abstract Double calc(T t, R r);
}
```

**StringClass.java**

```
public class StringClass extends Calculator<String, String>{

    @Override
    public Double calc(String t, String r) {
        return null; //TODO your logic
    }
}
```

**DoubleClass.java**

```
public class DoubleClass extends Calculator<Double, Double>{

    @Override
    public Double calc(Double t, Double r) {
        return null; //TODO your logic
    }
}
```

In case you want flexible return type.

**CalculatorV1.java**

```
public abstract class CalculatorV1<T, R, V> {
    public abstract V calc(T t, R r);
}
```

**DoubleClassV1.java**

```
public class DoubleClassV1 extends CalculatorV1<Double, Double, Integer>{

    @Override
    public Integer calc(Double t, Double r) {
        return null; //TODO your logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) but you can't use primitive datatypes with them.

To learn more about Generics see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226665/what-is-the-difference-in-usage-of-primitive-and-wrapper-data-type-and-what-is-t/43226959#43226959).

```
public abstract class AbstractCalculation<T, V> {
    public abstract T calc(T t, V v);
    ...
}
```

Now extend this class with Types.
Like:

```
class IntegerAddImpl extends AbstractCalculation<Integer, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer calc(Integer t, Integer v) {
        return t + v;
    }
}
class StringAddImpl extends AbstractCalculation<String, String>{
    @Override
    public String calc(String t, String v) {
        return t + v;
    }
}
```