# Updating entity with only non-null attributes of passed in object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an entity type with several fields. Some of them are references to other entities. I want to create a Rest API endpoint in Spring that lets users to update entities of this type.

Assume that I have an entity `User` that contains a list of friends. I only want to let users update some specific fields, such as `name`, `age` and `description`, of a user entity, and not list of friends.

Besides, I only want those attribute of the entity to be updated that the corresponding passed in values are not null.

```
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(path="",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void update(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.save(user);
    }
}
```

How can I make this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking `User` object as a parameter in your `update()` method you can take a [`DTO`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1612334/3094731) class that only defines the properties you need to change.

Define a class `UpdateUserDTO` like so

```
public class UpdateUserDTO {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    //other fields you want the clients to change.
    ...

}
```

Now this UpdateUserDTO can be used as a  data transfer object in your update method like so.

```
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(path="",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void update(@RequestBody UpdateUserDTO dto) {
        //validate your dto properties and then update your user entity. 
        userService.save(user);
    }

}
```

Comment: While this is a good hint it does not answer the question about the updating itself

Answer (score 0):

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
String newuserId=newuser.getUserId();
session.clear();
User user=userService.readUser(newuserId);
Property1 prop1=user.getProperty1();
List<Property2> prop2=user.getProperty2();
session.clear();
newuser.setProp1(prop1);
newuser.setProp2(prop2);
newuser.save(); //You should go through services and abstraction layers before saving aka it should be in the DAO implementation layer.
```

Your question needs improvement but try this answer.
You basically save the missing properties in some variables and you append them to your front end User object.
Based on the HQL output it seems like this way gets the user and adds the other properties to it.