# Parsing a RequestBody to params

Tags: java, json, postman, body-parser

I have a code which gets a body `POST` from *Postman*:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/dep", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public JsonResponse dep(@RequestBody String body) throws SQLException {

    Connection connection = ConnectionSingleton.getInstance().getConnection(env);

    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

    statement.close();
    connection.close();
    System.out.println("BODY #### "+body);
    return new JsonResponse("depreciated");
}
```

*Postman* sent:

```
{
    "idn":"MLCM00292",
    "monto":"9149.92"
}
```

And the string is like:

%7B%0A%09%22**idn**%22%3A%22**MLCM00292**%22%2C%0A%09%22**monto**%22%3A%22**9149.92**%22%0A%7D=

The words in bold are the parameters and their assigned values. I want to receive the parameters like variable. What its the correct way to get the params from a body in a POST request? What is missing in my code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) like this:

```
public JsonResponse dep(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body)
```

and then inside the method get the values like this:

```
String id = body.get("idn");
String monto = body.get("monto");
```

You can change the generics type for the `Map` class as it fits your needs. For example, if you are going to receive values of different types you can use it like `Map<String, Object> body`, then you could parse every value according to the data type (which you must know in advance). Something like:

```
String id = body.get("idn").toString();
double monto = Double.parseDouble(body.get("monto").toString());
```

For more complex data type I recommend you to create some custom POJOs or JavaBeans.

**Further readings**

- [Difference between DTO, VO, POJO, JavaBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans)

Comment: I get the next json `{
    "timestamp": "2018-10-24T15:12:26.847+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/irs/depreciation"
}` the message is `Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported`

Comment: `Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported`

Comment: @FranzSif Do you need to send the info as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? If not, you can send it as JSON by setting in the _Postman_ request > `Body` > `raw` > `JSON (application/json)` option.

Comment: @FranzSif Or you could try setting to the `@RequestMapping` the value `consumes = APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE`