# What does domain folder do in a spring boot project and what classes should be stored there?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, domain-driven-design

In a spring boot application I see a `domain` folder which includes `EntityName`, `EntityNameSomeDetails`, `SomeEntityNameResponse`, etc. I am not finding a proper documentation about this sort of architecture.

here is an example if domain folder that I am not clear what is the purpose of its each file. What classes I have to write there? What methods and variables I have to keep there, etc.

https://github.com/bigzidane/springboot-rest-h2-swagger/tree/master/src/main/java/com/es/challenge/domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a domain folder contains POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects). This folder basically stores classes that might or might not be entities, but follow a common structure:

1. fields
2. construstors
3. getters and setters

Answer (score 1):

The domain folder looks very much like the entity folder. Maybe it's just a different folder name given.

Comment: but in domain folder there are files that does no match any EER entities.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are actually looking for is the Spring boot project structure,which may not be the standard for every company/project,but [image: Here is one of many standards]

The project structure in the image is done by considering [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans)
Let me know:)

Comment: that's an understanding structure. however the one I'm looking into has a domain folder which I am not clear about its content.

Comment: By looking at the structure of the folder you have provided,I think the developer as written all the Entity,DTOs,Request and Response objects in the same package but which is not feasible because as the project grows and number of entities,DTOs,Req and Resp object increases,it will be hard to maintain.