# Java class classifications

Tags: java, javabeans, dto, facade

This sounds weird to ask,
but it's hard for me to understand the difference between a DTO,
a bean,
a `facadeBean`,
or a service when I read a java class.

Is there a way to detect the type of a class (except the class name).
Perhaps recommend an `eclipse or IntelliJ` plugin that could save me time.

Thanks!

Comment: See this anser: [Difference between DTO, VO, POJO, JavaBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1612671/7796663)

Comment: yes I read that, it's a theoretical definition. I need to know when I read java code installty to figure out which type of java class .

Comment: Why do you care? It matters when they're used, not when you glance at them. So the answer is "see how they're used".

Comment: it matters when you develop on legacy code.

Comment: A DTO class is a bean class.  I’m not sure what you mean by a facade bean, but as the name implies, it’s probably also a bean.  A service can be many things;  generally speaking, any class with a public method qualifies as a service.  Did you mean a web service, such as REST or SOAP?

Comment: Services manage data and server access for the client