# DTO and how this works exactly?

Tags: java, jpa, dto

**1.** **With DTO is response faster**

Why  ? When you make a endpoint without DTO for example @GetMapping("/{id}") which give you that exact "Employee" which have 20columns,but Domain need just 3columns, Frontend guy can from Json get that data by response.Name or response.LastName. What is exactly here faster which DTO ? Because that data is pulled from database anyway and with same speed with DTO or without no ?

Comment: @peterh There’s always an OO layer between Java and DBs by necessity, it’s a matter of how abstract (or not) that layer is.

Comment: Whether or not “separate” DTO layer(s) are useful is always context-dependent. Simplistic data and usage models may not need anything beyond plain JDBC or a bare minimum of ORM. Complex data/usage may benefit from one or more layers of abstraction, but there’s no “rules” regarding when, or even if.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1612334/573032) answers your question?

Comment: @DaveNewton No. Simple static SQL queries could do the same much more simply. What is going in the Java ORM, that is not even inffective work, it is ot crap work, it is sabotage.

Comment: @peterh Shrug. “Simply” is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **DTO** stands for *data transfer object*. It should consist of only primitive parts or other DTOs. And in particular shouldn't have any behaviour to it.

> 1. With DTO is response faster

Fetching and sending less data over the wire takes less time.

> 2. Edit response without DTO, can change data in the Database

When using Hibernate, [every returned entity is bound to the persistence context](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/objectstate.html) while the transaction is running, and the entity is not detached, every mutation of the entity is written back to the persisted entity without the need to invoke

```
repository.save(entity)
```

> 3. DTO is better with multiple requests

By itself, this statement is debatable.

You could create a DTO for `id 5` and keep it, for let's say 60 seconds, and when a successive call for the same id arrives the controller returns the cached DTO instead of doing a roundtrip to the db and creating an identical DTO.

Depending on the architecture and load different approaches could be considered.
For example 1st- or 2nd-level caches or views.